# Java Concurrency: Changes made by task submitted to executor visible after future.get()

Tags: java, concurrency, visibility

Suppose the task submitted to executor pool looks like

```
class Task implements Future<Boolean> {
 public HeavyClass heavyClass;
 public Task(HeavyClass heavyClass) {
    this.heavyClass = heavyClass;
 }

 public Boolean call() {
   try {
     //do changes to heavyClass
     return true;
   } catch(Exception e) {
      return false;
   }
 }
```

NOw in the calling thread I do

```
Future<boolean> future = executor.submit(new Task(heavyClass));
try {
  boolean success = future.get();
  if (success) {
      //Assume all changes made to heavyClass are visible
  }
}
```

Is this correct?According to my understanding this is not strictly correct. What is the best way to ensure correction in such scenarios?

Answer (score 2):

This should be fine.  Any viable implementation of `Future` will need to be written in such a way that marking it as completed involves a release fence, and checking for completion involves an acquire fence.  All prior changes to your `heavyClass` should be flushed when the `Future` is marked as completed, and should be guaranteed to be visible to other threads by the time the task's completed state is visible.

Relying on this, of course, means trusting that whoever implemented the executor knew what they were doing.  If you're using one of the core Java executors, you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

One of the nice things about `Future` is that you don't need to worry about this question. From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html):

> Memory consistency effects: Actions taken by the asynchronous computation happen-before actions following the corresponding Future.get() in another thread.

So even though your task does nothing to ensure inter-thread result visibility, the `Executor` implementation takes care of it for you.